# replace strings in column of pandas dataframe from ending with R to start with Right

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe which contains strings like this:

```
AAA BBB CCC R
```

I hope to change it to:

```
Right AAA BBB CCC.
```

I have tried: `df['A'].str.replace('R$', '^Right')`
But it returns:

```
AAA BBB CCC^Right
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with select values before `R` and then prepend `Right` to matched substring:

```
df.A = df.A.str.replace(r'(.+) R$', r'Right \1')
print (df)
                   A
0  Right AAA BBB CCC
```

Comment: Why should he do that? What does that do? How does it answer the question? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

With flexible [`pandas.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) method:

```
In [103]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['AAA BBB CCC R', 'aaa bbb dd rr']})                                                       

In [104]: df.A.where(~df.A.str.endswith('R'), "Right "+ df.A.str[:-2].astype(str) + ".", inplace=True)                       

In [105]: df                                                                                                                 
Out[105]: 
                    A
0  Right AAA BBB CCC.
1       aaa bbb dd rr
```